# Whenever $y'$ is in $\sin(y')$ or as a power, the degree of the polynomial equation is not defined, why?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In my textbook it is written that for $y'+ \sin\left(y'\right)= 0$ the degree is not defined.
Is it by definition or there is some reasoning behind this?

Comment: What do you think the degree ought to be? What's the degree of $$2y'-\frac16(y')^3+\frac1{120}(y')^5-\frac1{5040}(y')^7+\cdots?$$

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh so its not possible to assign a value, then its undefined 
thanks sooo much

Answer (score 0):

\begin{array}{l}
y' + \sin \left( {y'} \right) = 0\\
{\rm{Since, by   \ Maclaurin \ series \ expansion \ of \\}}\sin \left( x \right){\rm \ {is}}\\
\sin \left( x \right) = x - \frac{{{x^3}}}{{3!}} + \frac{{{x^5}}}{{5!}} - \frac{{{x^7}}}{{7!}} +  \cdots \\
{\rm{Then,the \ first \ order \ differential \ equation \ can \ be \ written \ as \ }}\\
y' + \sin \left( {y'} \right) = 0\\
y' + y' - \frac{{{{\left( {y'} \right)}^3}}}{{3!}} + \frac{{{{\left( {y'} \right)}^5}}}{{5!}} - \frac{{{{\left( {y'} \right)}^7}}}{{7!}} +  \cdots  = 0
\end{array}

Then from the above equation, it is clear that there are infinite terms in the equation, so the degree of the equation can not be defined.